# Компаратор функции sort для структуры

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector, struct, предикат

Имеется вектор структур вида :

```
struct Data
    {
        pair<uint16_t,uint16_t>my_pair;
        uint32_t c;
    };
vector<struct Data>My_Data;
```

И функция сортировки :

```
    void Sort()
    {
        bool my_custom_comparison(?)
        {
            ?
        }

        sort(My_Data.begin(),My_Data.end(),my_custom_comparison());
        cout<<"Sorting is over";
    }
```

Нужно отсортировать вектор My_Data по параметру "c". Обычным sort() это сделать нельзя. Какой компаратор надо написать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Начнем с того, что вложенных функций не бывает. `my_custom_comparison` всовывать в `Sort` не получится. Разве что лямбда-функцией.

А какой должна быть эта функция - читаем тут: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Итак,

```
sort(My_Data.begin(),My_Data.end(),[](const Data&a, const Data&b){return a.c < b.c;});
```

Если вы хотите именно с помощью функции - определите ее вне других функций как

```
bool my_custom_comparison(const Data&a, const Data&b)
{
    return a.c < b.c;
}
```

и пользуйтесь:

```
 sort(My_Data.begin(),My_Data.end(),my_custom_comparison);
```

Comment: спасибо. Да, с вложенной функцией глупо вышло) Вроде работает, но не  могли бы вы пояснить зачем в вызове функции sort использовать [ ] ?

Comment: `[связи](аргументы){тело}` - это безымянная функция (называется лямбда).

Comment: Потому что я писал "*Разве что лямбда-функцией.*" - вот это она и есть. Но на случай, если вы их еще не изучали, я привел решение и с обычной функцией.